# Warning: "The receiver of message 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is nil..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I got this warning:

> "The receiver of message 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is nil and returns a value of type 'CGSize' that will be garbage"

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSString *text = nil;
        NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (indexPath.section == FIRST_SECTION) {
        text = [_firstArray objectAtIndex:row];
    } else if (indexPath.section == SECOND_SECTION) {
        text = [_secondArray objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
           text = nil;
        NSLog(@"Wrong section");
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self myCell];
    UILineBreakMode lineBreakMode = cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode;

    CGFloat width = _tableView.contentSize.width - (kTableCellHPadding*2 + tableCellMargin*2);
    UIFont* font = cell.textLabel.font;
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

    if (size.height > kMaxLabelHeight) size.height = kMaxLabelHeight;

    return size.height + kTableCellVPadding*2;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the following code segment:

```
if (indexPath.section == FIRST_SECTION) {
    text = [_firstArray objectAtIndex:row];
} else if (indexPath.section == SECOND_SECTION) {
    text = [_secondArray objectAtIndex:row];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Wrong section");
}
```

In that in the else part, no value is assigned to the text variable. So, it remains as nil. So, XCode complains about it being null.

Comment: even if add a value to the "text" variable the warning still remains...(although the nil warning is gone now) the problem is not the text variable it is the CGSize that gets "garbaged" that bothers me the most....

Comment: Did you try building the code again after change? Also could you please post the updated code?

Comment: Update: i m adding else {
text = nil; }

Comment: When messaging nil, the return value is zero/nil/null in most cases.  Returning a struct is an exception and the compiler is correctly identifying a code path that will yield garbage.